# How do I perform a linq GroupBy across 3+ columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I start off with the following list

```
List items = new List();

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 1, MakeName = "Oldsmobile", ModelID = 2, ModelName =   "98 Regency" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 1, MakeName = "Oldsmobile", ModelID = 3, ModelName = "88 Delta" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 1, MakeName = "Oldsmobile", ModelID = 4, ModelName = "Alero" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 1, MakeName = "Oldsmobile", ModelID = 5, ModelName = "442" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 2, MakeName = "Buick", ModelID = 11, ModelName = "Skylark" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 2, MakeName = "Buick", ModelID = 13, ModelName = "Electra 225" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 2, MakeName = "Buick", ModelID = 14, ModelName = "Regal" });

items.add(new Vehicle { MakeID = 2, MakeName = "Buick", ModelID = 16, ModelName = "Enclave" });
```

But would like it converted to the following format:

```
List newList = new List();

items.add(new VehicleWithModelList { MakeID = 1, MakeName = "Oldsmobile", new List<Model> () { This list would contain the 4 oldsmobile models from above}});

items.add(new VehicleWithModelList { MakeID = 2, MakeName = "Buick", new List<Model> () { This list would contain the 4 buick models from above}});

public class Model {
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following linq to object query but I keep getting syntax errors stating it expects a semicolon before the last close parenthesis.

```
var newList = items.GroupBy(x => new {x.MakeID, x.ModelID, x.MakeName, x.ModelName}, (key, group) => new { MakeID = key.MakeID, MakeName = key.MakeName, ModelList = group.Select(z => new Model { ModelID = z.ModelID, ModelName = z.ModelName })).Cast< VehicleWithModelList >();
```

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does the class `Model` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
items.GroupBy(x => new { x.MakeID }).Select(x => new VehicleWithModelList
{
    MakeID = x.First().MakeID,
    MakeName = x.First().MakeName
    Models = x.Select(x => new Model 
    {
        ModelID = x.ModelID, 
        ModelName = x.ModelName
    }).ToList()
});
```

But if you give us the class definition for `Model` that would help

Looks like there is no need to group by MakeID and MakeName - MakeID should be enough unless for some reason it is possible to have the a MakeID with different MakeName's.

Comment: I added the Model class above.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a curly brace in the marked location below:

```
var newList = items.GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.MakeID,
        x.ModelID,
        x.MakeName,
        x.ModelName
    },
    (key, group) => new
        {
            MakeID = key.MakeID,
            MakeName = key.MakeName,
            ModelList = group.Select(z => new Model
                {
                    ModelID = z.ModelID,
                    ModelName = z.ModelName
                })
        } // <---- Here
    ).Cast<VehicleWithModelList>();
```

You would only want to group by the MakeId and MakeName or else you would get a different grouping for each unique ModelId and ModelName (which it doesn't seem like is the goal of your query:

```
var newList = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.MakeId, x.MakeName });
```

You can also lose the Cast by selecting directly into a `VehicleWithModelList` object:

```
(key, group) => new VehicleWithModelList
    {
        MakeID = key.MakeID
        ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed my syntax error.  One question, does this seem like it would perform the Grouping I need for the example above?

Comment: See updated answer. I suggest using LinqPad to test out your queries and get a visual representation of it (which is immensely helpful) http://www.linqpad.net/. The paid version is worth its weight in gold (how much does an application weigh these days?).